# hibernate error "could not execute native bulk manipulation query"

Tags: hibernate, timeout, bulk

I am running the following query:

```
    String sql = "Insert Into Mobr5.Abs_Gl_Settlement(Id_Entity,Dat_Eod,Id_Gl_Code,ID_STATUS,Amnt_Amount,DAT_CREATION,ID_CUSTOMER_CREATION) " 
            + "select Mobr5.Seq_Id_Gl_Settlement.Nextval As Id_Entity,TO_CHAR(SYSDATE-1,'DD-MON-YYYY'),Id_Parent_Gl_Code,'P',ChildAmount,Sysdate,100 from "  
    + "(select Gl.Id_Parent_Gl_Code, sum(Gst.Amnt_Amount) as ChildAmount From Mobr5.Abs_General_Ledger Gl," 
    + "Mobr5.Abs_Gl_Settlement Gst WHERE Gl.Id_Parent_Gl_Code IS NOT NULL AND Gl.Id_Gl_Code = Gst.Id_Gl_Code AND Gst.DAT_EOD=TO_CHAR(SYSDATE-1,'DD-MON-YYYY') GROUP BY Gl.Id_Parent_Gl_Code) z ";


    org.hibernate.Query query = getSession().createSQLQuery(updateQuery);
    int result = query.executeUpdate();
```

I am facing thw following error:

```
    2016-08-18 01:03:28,632  WARN [job-127                  ] (JDBCExceptionReporter.java    :100)  - SQL Error: 17002, SQLState: 08006
    2016-08-18 01:03:28,635 ERROR [job-127                  ]         (JDBCExceptionReporter.java    :101)  - IO Error: Connection timed out
    2016-08-18 01:03:28,637 ERROR [job-127                  ] (mmissionSettlementHandler.java:160)  - Exception occured dugring clearFees
    org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: could not execute native bulk manipulation query
at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:97)
at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.NativeSQLQueryPlan.performExecuteUpdate(NativeSQLQueryPlan.java:198)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.executeNativeUpdate(SessionImpl.java:1191)
at org.hibernate.impl.SQLQueryImpl.executeUpdate(SQLQueryImpl.java:357)
at com.sybase365.mobiliser.custom.project.persistence.dao.hibernate.CustomDaoHbnImpl.executeUpdate(CustomDaoHbnImpl.java:83)
at com.sybase365.mobiliser.custom.project.util.ClearingUtils.updateParentGl(ClearingUtils.java:667)
at com.sybase365.mobiliser.custom.project.jobs.cronjobs.eod.CommissionSettlementHandler.clearCommissions(CommissionSettlementHandler.java:151)
at com.sybase365.mobiliser.custom.project.jobs.cronjobs.eod.CommissionSettlementHandler.updateGLCommission(CommissionSettlementHandler.java:75)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:319)
at org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.service.importer.support.internal.aop.ServiceInvoker.doInvoke(ServiceInvoker.java:56)
at org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.service.importer.support.internal.aop.ServiceInvoker.invoke(ServiceInvoker.java:60)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:131)
at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:119)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.service.util.internal.aop.ServiceTCCLInterceptor.invokeUnprivileged(ServiceTCCLInterceptor.java:70)
at org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.service.util.internal.aop.ServiceTCCLInterceptor.invoke(ServiceTCCLInterceptor.java:53)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.service.importer.support.LocalBundleContextAdvice.invoke(LocalBundleContextAdvice.java:57)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:131)
at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:119)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2111.updateGLCommission(Unknown Source)
at com.sybase365.mobiliser.custom.project.services.endpoint.UtilityEndpoint.commissionGLSettlement(UtilityEndpoint.java:2972)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:319)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:161)
at com.sybase365.mobiliser.services.session.SessionManagementInterceptor.invoke(SessionManagementInterceptor.java:85)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor499.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:319)
at org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.service.importer.support.internal.aop.ServiceInvoker.doInvoke(ServiceInvoker.java:56)
at org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.service.importer.support.internal.aop.ServiceInvoker.invoke(ServiceInvoker.java:60)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:131)
at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:119)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.service.util.internal.aop.ServiceTCCLInterceptor.invokeUnprivileged(ServiceTCCLInterceptor.java:70)
at org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.service.util.internal.aop.ServiceTCCLInterceptor.invoke(ServiceTCCLInterceptor.java:53)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.service.importer.support.LocalBundleContextAdvice.invoke(LocalBundleContextAdvice.java:57)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:131)
at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:119)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2028.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:161)
at com.sybase365.mobiliser.framework.service.filter.impl.FilterAdvice.invoke(FilterAdvice.java:105)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor499.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:319)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
at org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.service.util.internal.aop.ServiceTCCLInterceptor.invokeUnprivileged(ServiceTCCLInterceptor.java:70)
at org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.service.util.internal.aop.ServiceTCCLInterceptor.invoke(ServiceTCCLInterceptor.java:53)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2134.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor499.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:319)
at org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.service.importer.support.internal.aop.ServiceInvoker.doInvoke(ServiceInvoker.java:56)
at org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.service.importer.support.internal.aop.ServiceInvoker.invoke(ServiceInvoker.java:60)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:131)
at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:119)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.service.util.internal.aop.ServiceTCCLInterceptor.invokeUnprivileged(ServiceTCCLInterceptor.java:70)
at org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.service.util.internal.aop.ServiceTCCLInterceptor.invoke(ServiceTCCLInterceptor.java:53)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.service.importer.support.LocalBundleContextAdvice.invoke(LocalBundleContextAdvice.java:57)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:131)
at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:119)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2028.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:161)
at com.sybase365.mobiliser.framework.service.response.ResponseCodeAdvice.invoke(ResponseCodeAdvice.java:153)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor499.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:319)
at org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.service.importer.support.internal.aop.ServiceInvoker.doInvoke(ServiceInvoker.java:56)
at org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.service.importer.support.internal.aop.ServiceInvoker.invoke(ServiceInvoker.java:60)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:131)
at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:119)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.service.util.internal.aop.ServiceTCCLInterceptor.invokeUnprivileged(ServiceTCCLInterceptor.java:70)
at org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.service.util.internal.aop.ServiceTCCLInterceptor.invoke(ServiceTCCLInterceptor.java:53)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.service.importer.support.LocalBundleContextAdvice.invoke(LocalBundleContextAdvice.java:57)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:131)
at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:119)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2028.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:161)
at com.sybase365.mobiliser.framework.service.response.ResponseCodeAdvice.invoke(ResponseCodeAdvice.java:153)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor499.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:319)
at org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.service.importer.support.internal.aop.ServiceInvoker.doInvoke(ServiceInvoker.java:56)
at org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.service.importer.support.internal.aop.ServiceInvoker.invoke(ServiceInvoker.java:60)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:131)
at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:119)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.service.util.internal.aop.ServiceTCCLInterceptor.invokeUnprivileged(ServiceTCCLInterceptor.java:70)
at org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.service.util.internal.aop.ServiceTCCLInterceptor.invoke(ServiceTCCLInterceptor.java:53)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.service.importer.support.LocalBundleContextAdvice.invoke(LocalBundleContextAdvice.java:57)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:131)
at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:119)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2028.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:161)
at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.aopalliance.MethodSecurityInterceptor.invoke(MethodSecurityInterceptor.java:64)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:90)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2125.commissionGLSettlement(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:319)
at org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.service.importer.support.internal.aop.ServiceInvoker.doInvoke(ServiceInvoker.java:56)
at org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.service.importer.support.internal.aop.ServiceInvoker.invoke(ServiceInvoker.java:60)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:131)
at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:119)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.service.util.internal.aop.ServiceTCCLInterceptor.invokeUnprivileged(ServiceTCCLInterceptor.java:70)
at org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.service.util.internal.aop.ServiceTCCLInterceptor.invoke(ServiceTCCLInterceptor.java:53)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.service.importer.support.LocalBundleContextAdvice.invoke(LocalBundleContextAdvice.java:57)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:131)
at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:119)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1990.commissionGLSettlement(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:319)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
at com.sybase365.mobiliser.framework.gateway.security.filters.standard.InternalServiceCallAuthenticator.invoke(InternalServiceCallAuthenticator.java:114)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2007.commissionGLSettlement(Unknown Source)
at com.sybase365.mobiliser.custom.project.jobs.cronjobs.eod.UpaisaEODProcessor$1.doInTransaction(UpaisaEODProcessor.java:89)
at com.sybase365.mobiliser.custom.project.jobs.cronjobs.eod.UpaisaEODProcessor$1.doInTransaction(UpaisaEODProcessor.java:56)
at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:130)
at com.sybase365.mobiliser.custom.project.jobs.cronjobs.eod.UpaisaEODProcessor.execute(UpaisaEODProcessor.java:56)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor515.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:319)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
at com.sybase365.mobiliser.framework.gateway.security.filters.standard.InternalServiceCallAuthenticator.invoke(InternalServiceCallAuthenticator.java:114)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2133.execute(Unknown Source)
at com.sybase365.mobiliser.money.jobs.task.cronjob.impl.CronjobLauncher.doExecute(CronjobLauncher.java:300)
at com.sybase365.mobiliser.money.jobs.task.cronjob.impl.CronjobLauncher.doExecute(CronjobLauncher.java:246)
at com.sybase365.mobiliser.money.jobs.task.cronjob.impl.CronjobLauncher.call(CronjobLauncher.java:147)
at com.sybase365.mobiliser.money.jobs.task.cronjob.impl.MDCCallable.call(MDCCallable.java:44)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I have searched through the internet but found nothing useful.
as per my perception, it is because i am using Query instead of SQLQuery. Please suggest.

Comment: The error message seems quite straightforward: connection time out. Is your query taking too long to execute?

Answer (score 2):

First your string is declare as sql, and on your createSQLQuery, you have updateQuery. That would create a problem on the execute because updateQuery could have anything else.

Now, lets say sql is updateQuery. Then on your execution you need to know which database you are sending the script. In my case for Oracle 11g createSQLQuery does not work. I could only  have it working for createNativeQuery.

So your code should look like:

```
String qry = "INSERT INTO tableName (col1, col2, col3...) VALUES (val1, val2, val3...)";
EntityManagerFactory emfSandBOX = <Your entity manager factory>;
EntityManager manager = emfSandBOX.createEntityManager();
manager.getTransaction().begin();
org.hibernate.Query query = manager.createNativeQuery(qry);
query.executeUpdate(); // Return 1 if executed
manager.getTransaction().commit();
manager.close();
```